# Parse GMT string to local

Tags: java

I've a `date = 2011-04-17T22:02:00.001-07:00` that I'm parsing using SDF

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
formatter.parse(date)
```

I It doesnt support -07:00 but -0700 works. What should change in the format?

Comment: Try using [TimeZone](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) it might help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that `SimpleDateFormat` doesn't support ISO8601 time zone formats. If you know for certain that your time zone will always end in the format of `-##:##` (or `+##:##`) then you could just remove the last `:` so that your existing formatter works. E.g. this parses your date:

```
String input = "2011-04-17T22:02:00.001-07:00";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
Date date = sdf.parse(input.replaceAll(":(..)$", "$1"));
```

Be careful however, apparently ISO8601 allows for some variations whereby this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at :

[Converting ISO 8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date)

it talks about this issue specifically..

Comment: I really dont want to use an api just for simple parsing.